# Como validar que mi input sea menor a un numero y me de un mensaje en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un input y si en ese input se escribe un numero mayor a 100, pues que me salga una **alert()**
diciéndome numero no puede pasar de 100, quiero lograr esto sin la necediad de un **Submit**. Que sea en tiempo real

El me valida que mi input permita solo numero, pero aun no logro mi problema planteado

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <input type="text" id="cobertura" name="cobertura" onkeypress="return checka(event)" maxlength="3" />
   </form>
    <script>
        function checka(e) {
            // SOLO ACEPTA NUMERO
        tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (tecla == 8) {
            return true;
        }
        patron = /[0-9]+$/;
        tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
        return patron.test(tecla_final);
            // END

            //ESTA PARTE ES LA QUE QUIERO VALIDAR
        var num= document.getElementById('cobertura').value;

        if (num> 100) {
            alert('Numero no puede pasar de 100');
            return false;
        }
            // END
    }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias @Excorpion tomare esa sugeencia para la proxima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola mi amigo cómo estás.

Lo que yo haría en tu caso sería poner un evento que escuche cada que escribo en el input para que de esa manera constantemente pueda estar validando.

Lo hago de manera sencilla pero ya tu le puedes agregar toda la dificultad, estilos y demás que quieras, o si es caso un framework.

```js
 // guardamos el input en el que el usuario escribe
    const input = document.querySelector('input');

    //ejecutamos el evento que escucha cuando se escribe
    input.addEventListener('input', e => {
      //guardamos el valor actual del input
      const value = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value);

      //si el valor se pasa de 100 lo reseteamos a 0 y mostramos la alerta
      if (value > 100) {
        input.value = 0;
        alert('Por favor ingresa un número menor a 100');
      }
    });
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <title>Respuesta de stack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Escribe un número" />
  </body>

</html>
```

Espero te halla servido, el código me parece que está bien explicado pero igual te dejo algunas referencias utilizadas para que te guíes:

Eventos:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Evento tipo "input":
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

`alert()`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScrihttps://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/alertpt/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Espero te ayude, bye <3

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, ya leeré esos enlaces que me dejaste

Comment: Una pregunta esto funciona si tengo varios input? es decir si tengo otro input pero no quiero que me arroje una alert, este se ve afectado, ese queryselector puede tomarse por id y no por input?

Comment: @TheRiddler si señor, lo puedes hacer cómo gustes, ya sea con varios inputs o con uno solo, si es con uno sólo te recomiendo cómo tu dices, por el id, si són varios pues le pones el mismo evento a cada uno

Answer (score 0):

Para los que deseen hacer la validación por id y no por input

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="cobertura" name="cobertura" style="width: 150px"  placeholder="valor" onkeydown="cien()" />
  </body>
</html>
<script>
    function cien() {
        const input = document.getElementById('cobertura');
        input.addEventListener('input', e => {
            const value = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value);
            if (value > 100) {
                input.value = 0;
                alert('Por favor ingresa un número menor a 100');
            }
        });
   }
</script>
```